# Possible to get dummy data (1 row) for all fields in the GA Schema?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-api, export-to-excel

I am working on a data integration project I'm wondering how to get a sample Excel or Google Sheet file with example data for all the GA fields in the current schema:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

I just need one row of data to review. Is there any way to get dummy data or test data? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Maybe something exists somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

GA provides a sample dataset for this. You can check the instructions on how to access it [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7586738?hl=en). You can then query the dataset and [download the results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#downloading_and_saving_query_results_from_a_ui).

Keep in mind that GA schema contains RECORDs and REPEATED fields, for example, `customDimensions`, so you might need to adapt the results so it can be downloaded as a CSV file, to then import it in Excel or Google Sheets.

Finally, there's a [BigQuery connector for Excel](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-connector-for-excel) that you may want to try to visualize the sample dataset in Excel.